# Unable to debug the HQL Script

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

So I am trying to create a Hive Schema for the analysis of the `json` data stored in hdfs. I am referring to [this blog](https://chisqr.wordpress.com/2016/04/26/simple-twitter-sentiment-analytics-using-apache-flume-and-spark-part-1/) for creating Hive tables,Below is my Schema.hql

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE base_tweets4 (
`id` BIGINT,
created_at STRING,
`source` STRING,
favorited BOOLEAN,
retweet_count INT,
 retweeted_status STRUCT<
  text:STRING,
  `user`:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
`entities` STRUCT<
  urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
  user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
  hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
 text STRING,
`user` STRUCT<
  screen_name:STRING,
  name:STRING,
  friends_count:INT,
  followers_count:INT,
  statuses_count:INT,
  verified:BOOLEAN,
  utc_offset:INT,
  time_zone:STRING>,
in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/twitteranalytics/base/';


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE incremental_tweets4 (
 `id` BIGINT,
  created_at STRING,
 `source` STRING,
  favorited BOOLEAN,
  retweet_count INT,
  retweeted_status STRUCT<
  text:STRING,
  `user`:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
  `entities` STRUCT<
  urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
  user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
  hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
  text STRING,
  `user` STRUCT<
  screen_name:STRING,
  name:STRING,
  friends_count:INT,
  followers_count:INT,
  statuses_count:INT,
  verified:BOOLEAN,
  utc_offset:INT,
  time_zone:STRING>,
  in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
 )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/twitteranalytics/incremental/';



CREATE VIEW reconcile_view AS
SELECT t1.* FROM
(SELECT * FROM base_tweets4
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM incremental_tweets4) t1
 JOIN
 (SELECT id FROM
  (SELECT * FROM base_tweets4
  UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM incremental_tweets4) t2
   GROUP BY id) s
     ON t1.id = s.id




  CREATE TABLE candidate_score (
  candidate_name STRING,
   sentiment_score DOUBLE
   )
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
  LOCATION '/twitteranalytics/candidate_score/';
```

On executing the above script I am getting the error as follows,

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive 
common-1.1.0-cdh5.13.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 49.294 seconds
OK
Time taken: 3.19 seconds
FAILED: ParseException line 21:0 missing EOF at 'CREATE' near 'id'
WARN: The method class 
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.
```

Upon searching in different blogs I found that this could be the error because of the `key words` being used as the name of the variables, and this could be resolved adding `backticks` to the variable name. But that does not seem to be working. I may be missing something which is throwing me this error.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your DDL of two tables and it worked for me without any modification. Can you please retry it again. if possible please attach the JSon file so that I can try end to end.

Comment: My JSON data is a sample tweet retrieved using FLUME and stored in hdfs. I am using Cloudera vm.

Comment: in your third DDL you have not used back tick `` in "id" columns while selecting it . I don't think it would be a problem but please check it once.